# In Flutter, inside Row widget, I have taten two Text widget, I want space between them (like we do with "&nbsp" in Html),

Tags: flutter

In the above code I used Sized Box Widget but it didn't gives me anything?
How can I add space in it?

Android Emulator Images

[image]

```dart
Padding(padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(24, 4, 24, 0),
         child: 
              Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Discount',
                                style: AppTheme.of(context).subtitle2,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 20,),
                              Text(
                                '₹ ${Provider.of<Cart>(context,listen:false).discountPrice}',
                                style: AppTheme.of(context).subtitle1,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: what is the parent widget of Padding

Comment: It's in the <Widget>[]
of Column Widgets

Comment: try to wrap with `Expanded`

Answer (score 0):

wrap with container/sizebox and add in row  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround

Answer (score 0):

Using `TextSpan()` widget is better than instead of `Row()`. Like that.

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
  children: [
    TextSpan(text: 'Discount',style: AppTheme.of(context).subtitle2,),
    WidgetSpan(
        child: SizedBox(
      width: 20, // your of space
    ),),
    TextSpan(text: "${Provider.of<Cart(context,listen:false).discountPrice}",
style: AppTheme.of(context).subtitle1,),
  ],
),),
```

**Edit:** but I think in your question your code and your screen shoot is different. Please ask clearly. ** My answer is to space between horizontal text widget. **

Answer (score 0):

That's a quite good approach to use SizedBox in this case, but you need to set width instead of height.